# Chrome windows on launcher panel: expand into several

Tags: 18.04, gnome, google-chrome, ubuntu-gnome

When I have several Chrome windows open, it looks like this:

[image]

However I'd like each Chrome window to occupy its own space, like this:

[image]

How would I do that?